# compiling objective-c 2.0 under ubuntu with clang

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, objective-c-2.0, llvm-clang

What do I got: Ubuntu 12.04, clang, gnustep-devel, gnustep, libobjc2

So I'm trying to compile a simple program

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
NSLog(@"Hi");
[pool drain];

return 0;
}
```

compiling like this: `clang prog.m -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString`
and no problem, everything is perfect and works fine

BUT if I want to use autoreleasepool:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }

return 0;
}
```

and compile it the same way I got errors:

```
undefined reference to `objc_autoreleasePoolPush' 
undefined reference to `objc_autoreleasePoolPop'
```

I've googled for a long time and didn't find the solution, maybe someone got the same problem resolved?

Comment: Make sure you are using gnustep-libobjc one, not one from gcc, ie. you could try getting rid of libobjc* deb packages, gnustep's one that should be built with cmake. I'm not sure which clang is needed, I had problems with ObjC++ and so I had to build clang from trunk.